# Power USB ports On or OFF using nodejs

Tags: node.js, usb

I'm trying to programatically enable or disalbe **power** to a USB port which will be the host of a simple motor. While I have found different ways to detect (like usb-detection from bpm) USB devices or read data, I have yet to find any solutions that allow to actually turn the USB port on or off.

I am using ubuntu 18.04, so linux dependencies aren't a problem, but the solution must be implemented in Node JS as it will have various functionalities, not as simple as running a script